# Install on Toshiba ac100

Tags: system-installation, ac100

The Toshiba AC100 netbook is a Tegra 2 machine.

Is there a possibility that I might be able to install Ubuntu (any version) on it?

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/37619/what-kernels-exist-for-toshibas-ac100-and-where-to-get-them

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kernels exist for Toshiba's ac100 and where to get them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37619/what-kernels-exist-for-toshibas-ac100-and-where-to-get-them)

Answer (score 4):

For people to have at least one direct answer:
(yes there is a Ubuntu kernel in this url)

http://kotelett.no/ac100/phh/Android2.2/

This is a guide on how to do it - You shouldn't risk trying it if you don't know what you're doing:
http://salaliitto.com/~gildean/ac100/wiki/phh/

(and whenever they use Ubuntu5.tar.lzma you take the Ubuntu7.tar.gz and whenever they use boot.img you use boot.32.img)

--- but before you do anything of it, try your luck with the guide as it is...

I don't take any responsibility for broken devices

Answer (score 4):

Work is actively in progress to add support for the AC100 to Ubuntu as part of the 11.10 release.  Until this is complete (or for previous releases), there are a variety of recommendations floating around on the internet.

For my own device (not an AC100, but the dynabook from which the AC100s derive), I have had great success with the materials made available by the [AC100 team in launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ac100/). The description of the PPA includes links to known working images and instructions for installation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways doing this.
This is a guide on installing phh's latest ubuntu 10.10 image with .32 kernel.
It has working sound, suspend etc.
Check it out here: http://ac100.tunk.org/wiki/phh

Answer (score 1):

At the present date, there's a how-to <sup>*(last edited 2012-04-26)*</sup> for the installation of the Ubuntu 12.04 on the Toshiba AC100:

[Ubuntu Wiki :: Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on the AC100](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100/)

> Ubuntu on AC100 is currently an official demonstration of the Ubuntu ARM port and works fairly well. This page collects information necessary to get a working Ubuntu 12.04 port on the AC100.

**Minimum requisites:**

- Mini-usb cable
- Host computer with linux (virtual or physical)
- Usb-stick or sd-card (min. 1GB)
- About 1-2h of your life (depending on the download-time)

Answer (score 0):

I could install in a similar machine. I had to boot the live cd with the options: acpi=off and noapic. After installation I had to edit grub to add this options.

Comment: ac100 doesn't have a cdrom drive nor does the istaller support the ac100 (yet). Hopefully for Oneiric ogra will have a working installer though.