# What kernels exist for Toshiba's ac100 and where to get them?

Tags: installation, kernel, arm, ac100

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install on Toshiba ac100](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35277/install-on-toshiba-ac100)

I have an ac100 and know that there is the possibility to flash a custom kernel and boot Ubuntu that way. Also, there are several kernel-versions around that work only in certain circumstances.

What I want to know now is what versions there are and where to get them. I'll ask another question for how to install them, what the install options are (internal eMMC and/or SD-Card/USB-flashdrive).

EDIT: It looks like everything is changing too fast to get a satisfying answer.